# How to geotag photos uploaded to google photos

Tags: google-photos, geotagging

I've uploaded some photos to google photos, these photos do not have any location information in their EXIF metadata as my camera didn't have the GPS enabled at the time of capturing images.

Now I want to geotag (add location information) these photos. Since I know the location (GPS coordinates) where these pictures are taken I am looking for an option to geotag them in google photos.

It seems that the google photos app does not have any option to geotag the photos.
Is there any way I can geotag the photos from google photos?

Answer (score 1):

You can geotag the photos from google photos web site.
Follow the below steps to geotag your google photos.

- Go to [photos.google.com](https://photos.google.com)
- Select the photos that you want to geotag
- Click the options menu and select `Edit Location`
- Type the location and choose the appropriate one from the dropdown
- Done. The photos are geotagged now

Comment: This does not allow you to geotag a photo using coordinates, you have to tag it to an already established google map location